# Necesito un popup en javascript que se abra y al clickar en algún elemento que se cierre a los 3 segundos

Tags: javascript, html

Hola necesito ayuda para hacer una `popup` en `javascript` que se abra y al clickar en algún elemento se cierre tras pasar 3 segundos después de haber clickado ¿Seria posible? y también que recargue la página en la que se estaba al cerrarse el `popup`. Un saludo

Mi código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popUp(URL) {
    window.open(URL, 'Twitter', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=300,height=200,left = 390,top = 50');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un `alert` de `JS` para lograrlo:

```js
function redireccionar() {
    alert("Has presionado el botón!");
    setTimeout("location.href='https://es.stackoverflow.com'", 3000);
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="redireccionar()">Haz click</button>
```